# Android application - Is it possible to figure out if a person is walking or using a vehicle using google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, google-maps-api-2

I am building an android application. I would like to know automatically if the user if walking or using a vehicle like a car when the application is switched on.

I'll be obviously using google maps to do it. But can someone give me pointer on how should I go about it.

---

Thanks

Comment: Leaving aside the specifics of coding, what criteria do you propose to use to distinguish walking from car use? It is quite likely that the user will be stationary in both cases when starting your app.

Comment: The user is going to switch on the application before he sets off from one place to another and switch if off when he reaches his destination. I would like to find out whether he took a car or he walked..

Comment: It is very simple to distinguish between both. have you ever walked with 15 km/h ? Probaly not possible. so simply introduce a threshold, if exceeded then not walking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could use the new Activity Recognition API that is part of Google Play Services. You can find more information in [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html) link.